# Use of the second differential without an initial equation

Tags: calculus

I'm having some trouble finding minimums using the second differential without being provided an initial equation. Here is the question:

> A piece of wire of length 60 cm is cut into two pieces. Each piece is then bent to form the perimeter of a rectangle which is twice as long as it is wide. Find the lengths of the two pieces of wire if the sum of the areas of the rectangles is to be a minimum.

Let $m$ and $n$ be the lengths so that $m + n = 60$. Taking $m$, the perimeter of its rectangle will be:

$$\begin{align}
M & = 2W + 2L \\
& = 2W + 2(2W) = 6W \\
\\
Area_m & = W \times L = 2W^2 \\
& = 2\left(\frac{M}{6}\right)^2 \\
& = \frac{M^2}{18} \\
\\
Area_{total} = f(x) & = \frac{M^2}{18} + \frac{N^2}{18} \\
& = \frac{M^2}{18} + \frac{(60 - M)^2}{18} \\
& = \frac{M^2}{18} + \frac{3600 + M^2}{18} \\
& = \frac{M^2}{9} + 200 \\
\\
f'(x) & = \frac{2}{9}M
\end{align}$$
But that's where I get stuck down the rabbit hole. I know my approach is incorrect, because the given answer is 30 x 30. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(60-M)^2 = 3600 - 120M + M^2$ instead of $3600 + M^2$.

Comment: D'oh! Thank you, that leads me to my answer :)